# 'fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I successfully compiled a codebase on my macbook and also on a server with intel compilers. When I run it through my company's continuous integrating testing, which has its own build system, I am getting the following error in the compilation.

```
..\corecrt_math.h(415): error C2668: 'fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function
..\corecrt_math.h(300): note: could be 'int fpclassify(long double) noexcept'
..\corecrt_math.h(295): note: or       'int fpclassify(double) noexcept'
..\corecrt_math.h(290): note: or       'int fpclassify(float) noexcept'
..\corecrt_math.h(415): note: while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=kc20::wrapped_int8::underlying
        ]
/path/to/file/kernel.cpp(69): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool isnan<integer_type>(_Ty) noexcept' being compiled
        with
        [
            integer_type=kc20::wrapped_int8::underlying,
            _Ty=kc20::wrapped_int8::underlying
        ]
```

Note that `kc20` is a namespace that contains the `wrapped_int8` struct. `wrapped_int8` is defined as

```
struct alignas(1) wrapped_int8 {
  using underlying = int8_t;
  int8_t value;
  // some other function definitions
};
```

so `kc20::wrapped_int8::underlying` is just `int8_t`. In the error message, it seems to only list the first 3 overloads of `fpclassify` in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify . My code should be using case (4) of this link since it's an integral type. What is the ambiguity here?

Comment: [Looks like MS didn't implement 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fpclassify?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @user4581301 Oh I see. How did you know this CI used microsoft compilers?

Comment: https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt/corecrt_math.h#L289-L299

Comment: cl.exe is the name of the Microsoft C++ compiler and the error message given looks like output from cl.exe. Mind you Cl might be See Eye not See Ell and the font fooled me. Well, the error message still looks decidedly Microsoftian.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh sorry about that, I just spelled out the acronym (continuous integration).