# Is the microsoft C++ compiler smart enough to know std::isnan isn't called on a integral type in my code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

This is related to my earlier post ['fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71863599/fpclassify-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function?noredirect=1#comment126991680_71863599)

I attempted to correct the code that produced the error. The original code looked like the following.

```
struct alignas(1) wrapped_int8 {
  using underlying = int8_t;
  int8_t value;
  // some other function definitions
};

template <typename T>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = std::isnan(val);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{  
  func<wrapped_int8::underlying>(4);
}
```

It failed to compile using microsoft compilers because of the `fpclassify` overload ambiguity issue and the lack of an integral overload to `fpclassify` for the microsoft build.

So I changed the `func` to:

```
template <typename T>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = std::is_integral<T>::value ? false : std::isnan(val);
}
```

but this still gives the same error. With my code's logic, if `T` is an integral type, we should never have to call `std::isnan`, so there shouldn't be an issue with `fpclassify`, but is the compiler smart enough to know that `std::isnan` won't be called on integral types? If so, why is it still producing this error? If not, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If C++17 is allowed

```
template <typename T>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = false;
  if constexpr (!std::is_integral<T>::value)
    mask = std::isnan(val);
}
```

If C++14 or older

```
template <typename T>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = std::isnan(val);
}

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = false;
}
```

You also may hack `std::isnan` for `int8_t`

```
namespace std {
  bool isnan(int8_t val) noexcept { return false; }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can only use C++14. This is my company codebase and we have not enabled support for C++17 yet

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you please explain what is wrong with my code? I don't get what the issue is. Isn't `std::is_integral<T>::value` known at compile time?

Comment: It's a compile time expression, but both branches of `if (true) ... else ...;`  must be compiled, and the else-branch results to the same error. Similar to `auto mask = true ? false : syntax-error;` that with `syntax-error` will not be compiled.

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking the else branch wouldn't be compiled in this case. I really don't know how compilers work honestly.

Comment: Ahh, your edited example makes it clear

Comment: `if-constexpr` since C++17 is what you want, but C++17 is not allowed.

Comment: I think we're in the process of enabling C++17, but I'm not sure what the timeline is. For your C++14 implementation, is there anywhere to do it without having to introoduce the second template parameter?

Comment: @David - It's not so much that the compiler can't evaluate a compile-time constant.   It's that the standard requires both the if and the else to be diagnosed in an `if` (if it isn't `if constexpr` that was introduced in later standards) and both possible results of a `?:` ternary expression.

Comment: @David You may overload `std::isnan` although it is not welcome.

Comment: @273K I did think about doing that too. Why is it not welcome? Is it generally frowned upon to overload an STL function?

Comment: @273K Wait, doy ou mean overload `std::fpclassify` or `std::isnan`? I think `std::fpclassify` is the issue here and not `isnan`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `if constexpr` to discard the call to `std::isnan(val)`.

```
template <typename T>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = [&] {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
      return false;
    else
      return std::isnan(val);
  }();
}
```

C++14 version

```
template<class T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool>::type 
mask_impl(T val) {
  return false;
}

template<class T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>::type 
mask_impl(T val) {
  return std::isnan(val);
}

template <typename T>
void func(T val) {
  auto mask = mask_impl(val);
}
```

Comment: So I cannot use C++17. I can only use C++14. But I am a little confused. Isn't `std::is_integral<T>::value` known at compile time?