# Is it discouraged to overload STL functions?

Tags: c++, stl, overloading

I was wondering if it is discouraged to overload an STL function, and if so, why?

I ran across an issue yesterday, where I found that `std::fpclassify` doesn't have an integral overload on microsoft compilers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fpclassify?view=msvc-170) as it does for other compilers (see (4) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fpclassify).

I ran across this issue when I tried to compile

```
T var; // T can be an integral type
std::isnan(var); //
```

using microsoft C++ compiler.

I already have a working solution to solve this issue that didn't involve overloading `std::fpclassify`, but I did consider maybe just writing an overload for `std::fpclassify` myself, but it seems it would have gotten hairy because the code might be compiled using non-microsoft compilers, in which case, we would already have the integral overload defined.

Comment: _"...It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below...."_ [Extending the namespace std](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it discouraged to overload STL functions?

You aren't allowed to add any overloads into the `std` namespace. It's fine to add overloads into custom namespaces.

> and if so, why?

Because the standard says so. Probably so that your program won't break when the standard (implementation) changes.

Comment: In the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866182/is-the-microsoft-c-compiler-smart-enough-to-know-stdisnan-isnt-called-on-a/71866237?noredirect=1#comment126995809_71866237 by 273K, isn't the overload placed in the `std` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no issue as long as you are not trying to place your custom overload inside the namespace `std`, because that is undefined except in some cases.

Consider `std::swap` where you are even encouraged to provide an overload when swapping two objects should do something that `std::swap` cannot do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace X {

struct foo {
    int value;
    bool operator<(const foo& other) { return value < other.value; }
};

void swap(foo& a, foo& b) noexcept {
    std::cout << "swap\n";
    std::swap(a.value,b.value);
}

}

int main() {
    std::vector<X::foo> v{{2},{1}};
    std::iter_swap(v.begin(),v.begin()+1);   // calls X::swap
    std::cout << v[0].value << " " << v[1].value << "\n";

    std::vector<int> w{2,1};
    std::iter_swap(w.begin(),w.begin()+1);  // calls std::swap
    std::cout << w[0] << " " << w[1];
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/eve6Tzch3):

```
swap
1 2
1 2
```

This relies on ADL, which means it wont work for fundamental types or types from `std`. Only if you wrap them inside a custom class inside some namespace like above you can use it for `int` and the like.