# Different results of std::isinf for different types and different compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution

Compiling with MSVC(v19.33), this does not compile (C2668 ambiguous call to overloaded function):

```
std::cout << std::isinf(0) << std::endl;
```

But this compiles:

```
std::cout << std::isinf(0.0) << std::endl;
```

However, in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf), it says:

> 4. A set of overloads or a function template accepting the arg argument of any integral type. Equivalent to (2) (the argument is cast to double).

It seems like the function has existed in the standard since C++11.

If I understood correctly, the first code should be equivalent to the second one, shouldn't it? Does this mean MSVC hasn't implemented the overloaded functions yet, or am I missing something?

(In contrast, if I use gcc or clang, the above examples compile without problems).

Comment: Reading the spec it seems like you are correct that MSVC got it wrong. But anyway - why do you want to check if an integer value is infinite (will never be true) ?

Comment: @wohlstad Just found those results during debugging, and I wanted to know if my understanding is okay or not :) The example codes are just examples, not parts of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Microsoft's implementation, the definition of the `isinf` is as follows (copied from [here](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt/corecrt_math.h#L406)):

```
template <class _Ty>
_Check_return_ inline bool isinf(_In_ _Ty _X) throw()
{
    return fpclassify(_X) == FP_INFINITE;
}
```

The problem with Microsoft's `fpclassify` is the missing overload for integral types. For more details, see:

['fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71863599/580083).

I agree with the opinion that MSVC is wrong here (however, it seems that they don't care).

Comment: Is there any reason they don't implement it? (e.g. some complicated backward compatibility problem, etc.) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @starriet I have no idea. You would need to ask the Microsoft developers for a reason.